# old version google browser Link to an open browser need close now browser

Tags: puppeteer

For some reasons, I need to use an old version of Google Chrome, version 8.0.4147.125. First, I modified the shortcut like this

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222

Try to link to an open browser with the following code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs');
const axios= require("axios")

var dataArr = [];
async function run(){
    
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:9222/json/version`);
    const webSocketDebuggerUrl = response.data.webSocketDebuggerUrl;
    console.log(webSocketDebuggerUrl)
    const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
        browserWSEndpoint: webSocketDebuggerUrl
        });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.goto("https://www.baidu.con");
    
 }
 run();
```

However, I found that there is no way to connect to the browser that has been opened. I need to close the browser that has been opened. When I click Close, it will automatically open a new browser

In this case, my previous login cookies are gone. What should I do

Any help would be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpc3T.png)

Comment: are you sure you wrote the correct chrome version? `8.0.4147.125` doesn't exist, closest was `8.0.552` but it was released in 2010 and 100% sure it was not compatible with any version of puppeteer library (first beta versions used ~chrome 60.x).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is related to the browser version, because the same code can be linked to the browser normally in the latest browser. The following is the download link of the browser 8.0.4147.125. Thank you very much  ！https://www.xinluobo.com/soft/llq_47139.html

Comment: ah, OK, but it is `84.0.4147.125` and you've mentioned `8.0.4147.125` :D that Chrome version was compatible with Puppeteer `5.1.0`. see which puppeteer version used which chromium in [`versions.js`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/versions.js). they guarantee to work only with the bundled version: simply because the DevTools API and chromium features change over time. you either try to downgrade to the mentioned, older puppeteer version or you will need to accept that due to breaking changes: not all API functions will be supported for older browsers.